# Save in logs files changes of Language Manager

Tags: logging, joomla, joomla3.0

I can not find how to write in log files of extentions Language Manager the following information: 

-user name 

-name of the constant 

- old value 

- new value

Please see the image
[image]
As I understand I need to write a hook and put this code in it:

`JLog::add('user:'.$userName .' constantName:'.$constantName.' oldValue:'.$oldValue.' newValue:'.$newValue,JLog::INFO,'com_language.monitoring');`

But as I am new to Joomla, I do not know how to do it in a proper way, so after updating Joomla version everything still works.

Thank you

Comment: The full answer with plugin written was given here http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/save-in-logs-files-changes-of-language-manager

Answer (score 0):

Create a system plugin, and then log the data in the `onExtensionAfterSave` event that is triggered when a save activity takes place on the language extension.

This might sound a bit overwhelming if you're new to Joomla, but plugins are super easy to create (just duplicate an easy system plugin and then modify it and finally install it and enable it).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But I have much better answer here http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/save-in-logs-files-changes-of-language-manager